# How to configure horizontal layout for aem touch ui dialog

Tags: dialog, aem

I have a touch ui requirement where I need to place 2 text boxes side by side like the older ExtJs size widget. Is there a `layout` I can set to item to place those objects next to each other. For the older implementation I had written a custom widget with hbox layout. I think this should be supported now but cant find it in the docs. Any references will help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [fixedColumn layout](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns/index.html)

> Please note that you will **not** see the columns in floating dialog mode, this layout is intended for **fullscreen dialog**, see the screenshots.

Here is an example I put together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Sample"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    mode="edit">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <columns
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <col1
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        jcr:title="General"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <filed1col1
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldDescription="sample filed1col1"
                                fieldLabel="filed 1 col 1"
                                name="./filed1col1"/>
                        </items>
                    </col1>
                    <col2
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        jcr:title="Phone Numbers"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <filed1col2
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldDescription="sample filed1col2"
                                    fieldLabel="filed 1 col 2"
                                    name="./filed1col2"/>
                        </items>
                    </col2>
                </items>
            </columns>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Dialog in floating mode
[image: Dialog in floating mode]

dialog in fullscreen mode
[image: dialog in fullscreen mode]

> As it is the case with any dialog related questions, you can write your own CSS to achive this functionality, however, you run the risk of dialog markup/classes changing in future which will render your CSS useless.